# Python : ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)

Tags: python, python-requests, importerror

This issue is coming right now. why i don't know. But i was not facing this issue before 2 / 3 days.
This error is coming, when my 'import request' starts running. I have tried every single solution on internet but nothing seems to worked.

```py
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"
"E:/IT Vedant/Rough Work/1mg.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\IT Vedant\Rough Work\1mg.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

My `C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py` *from* section didn't seem to have the required entries.

To resolve this, I added the following to that file:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from collections.abc import Sequence
```

Additionally my project .py file still had the legacy code line `import collections` which I replaced with the new code line `from collections.abc import Mapping`

Answer (score 3):

You are using python 3.10

try changing from
`from collections import Mapping`
to `from collections.abc import Mapping`

Comment: I have done this already. still not working

Comment: then pleas post your code and what you have tried aswell as the entrire stack trace

Comment: check here is the full error

Answer (score 3):

in You python 3.10 go to this link

```
C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\
```

and open file `__init__.py`

in this file change:

```
from collections import Mapping
```

to

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```